# Show that if Y is open in X and U is open in Y, then U is open in X

Tags: metric-spaces

I need help proving the following:
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subseteq X$ be a subspace. Show that if Y is open in X and U is open in Y, then U is open in X.

I know that if Y is open in X then ($\forall$$x$$\in$ Y) ($\exists$$r$>0) B($x$,$r$)$\subset$Y. The same goes if U is open in Y. But how can I prove that U is open in X? Should I use some other definitions?

Comment: $U$ open in $Y\implies U=A\cap Y$ where $A$ is  open in $X$;; Also $Y$ open in $X\implies U$ open in $X$

Comment: When you asked to proof "U is open in X", as in other places in math, don't try to **use the hypothesis** first, but try to prove the result(conclusion). And in proving the result, that is the time you may use your hypothesis.

Comment: okay guys, thanks a lot.

Comment: To claim "U is open in X". First, choose a point $x\in U$, since $U$ is open in $Y$, then there is a ball centered at $x$ and fully contained in $Y$. At the same time $Y$ is a subset of $X$, so this ball in trivially contained in $X$, so $x$ is an interior point of $X$. Since the point $x$ is arbitrarily chosen, then for every $x$ in $U$ is an interior point.

Comment: Oh. But is that enough to prove the statement or do I need to use something else?

Comment: My proof is valid and correct. There is no other definition or theorem to use. But for mathematical writing, one should have better write it in a more symbolic way and clear way. i.e. use the terminology like $\subseteq$, $\in$, and explicitly write down the ball like $B_r^U(x)$. I'm willing to write it down, but I've to study my exam. :) Maybe other one will help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Good luck with your exam :)

Answer (score 1):

According to definition of subspace topology, a set $A\subset Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $A=B\cap Y$ for some open set $B\subset X$.

So now $U$ being open in $Y$, there exists $A$ open in $X$ such that $U=A\cap Y$. Now $A,Y$ are open in $X$, hence their intersection (being finite intersection) is again open in $X$.

So, all you need to check is that, the subspace topology and the induced metric topology are same on $Y$ whenever you have $(X,d)$ a metric space. This I will leave as an exercise.

Comment: I think the OP's question is quite easy and trivial, but the theorem you used here are not and needs more things to say(and to prove). I personally think it is better to prove the OP's question directly by definition.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: Yes @Eric, in hindsight I realized it's better to directly prove it. :) I guess someone will provide that direct proof. So my "exercise" is heavyweight, it seems.